# Can one app access an app that has password protected?

Tags: permissions

On my Android, there is a feature that I can set password for app that I want to. Example, let's say I set a password for my gallery and then I install new app from play store or browser and the new app want to access my gallery. Can that new app access to my gallery?

Comment: What is that feature?

Comment: the feature is in Huawei phone and i don't know what it is. I just know that I can set password for app in settings.

Comment: Then it will all depend on the limits of that feature.

Comment: Password protection for apps usually protects their UI i.e. the activities won't appear in foreground without authorization. Such kind of protection doesn't protect app data. In case of gallery, the data which the app shows i.e. photos, videos etc. isn't owned by the gallery app. So even if the app is protecting all of its private data (e.g. by encryption), photos and videos are lying on shared storage. And any app with Storage permission can access that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, The other app wont be able to access this app but other app can access this app data if its not stored encrypted on device storage. Other app only need storage permissions to do that. If other app can access device storage then that app can access any unencrypted data stored on device. But it wont be able to access OS files which are stored in read-only partitions/folder without having root access